# Display list horizontally is not working with display inline

Tags: html, css, list, html-lists

I'm trying to print out my list horizontally but it isn't working with display inline. I also used `float: left;` and `position:cente`r but then it isn't centered horizontally.

PHP

```
foreach ($memberinfo as $info) 
{
    echo "<ul><li><a href='profile.php?user_id=" . $info['user_id'] . "'><img class='group_member_img' src='uploads/" . $info['avatar']  .   "'/><br>" . $info['surname'] . " " . $info['name'] . "</a></li></ul><br>";

}
```

CSS

```
.groupmember ul
{
    margin:0;
    list-style-type: none;
    text-align:center;

}

.groupmember ul li 
{
    display:inline;

}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating a new unordered list `ul` for every `$memberinfo`, so the `display:inline` is working, but the ul's remain like block elements.
Create the ul tag before the foreach and close it after it, so your list items will be displayed like you want:

```
echo "<ul>";
foreach ($memberinfo as $info) {
    echo "<li><a href='profile.php?user_id=" . $info['user_id'] . "'><img class='group_member_img' src='uploads/" . $info['avatar']  .   "'/><br>" . $info['surname'] . " " . $info['name'] . "</a></li>";
}
echo "</ul>";
```

By the way, the break line `br` tag is unnecessary because you want to put every li one beside the other.

Answer (score 1):

Using **`display: inline-block`** as suggests probably the right solution here.

```
.groupmember ul li {
    display:inline;
}
```

**`display: inline`** is not really useful for anything but **elements** that have **no nested elements** inside **them**.

Answer (score 1):

`display:inline` is very limited and doesn't allow any **block-level** styling to added to it.

You're better off using `display:inline-block` or using `float:left`.

Keep in mind that if you use floats then you need to set the overflow of the parent element to `overflow:auto` (use visible for IE < 8) and this should work. Use inline-block first.